# Request for resources (CSS, JS) being incorrectly redirected by htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I had a look at a few possible duplicates for this question but rewrite rules are fairly specific to projects so I couldn't find a suitable answer.

Crux of issue? Requests for certain files (CSS, JS & images) are being rewritten (I think) by the htaccess file.

I have an htaccess file set up to direct as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

It takes a URL like localhost/framework/booking/dashboard and rewrites to localhost/framework/index.php?controller=booking&action=dashboard

The relevant file structure inside my local www folder looks something like:

framework 
 -index.php
 -htaccess
 -views
  -Booking
   -dashboard.php
   -wuxia-blue.css

The CSS link in dashboard.php is as follows:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="wuxia-blue.css">
```

The HTTP request being made seems to be:
/framework/booking/wuxia-blue.css

It should be:
/framework/views/booking/wuxia-blue.css

Ideally, I'd like to use something similar to

```
href="<?php echo(CSS . "wuxia-blue.css"); ?>".
```

Where CSS is a defined constant in the application and where wuxia-blue.css (and all other css files) are contained in a predefined folder of stylesheets. Obviously this would apply to other assets like .js files and images.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to add base link change it to href="/views/booking/wuxia-blue.css"

Comment: Hmmm slight alteration to your comment. I used href="framework/views/booking/wuxia-blue.css". I'd like to use something relative in php like calling a constant to access the css file.

So, for instance: <?php echo(CSS . "wuxia-blue.css"); ?>. So methinks I need to edit question quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The htaccess rule is correct - the problem is with your folder structure.

When you create a relative link, it's relative to the current URL as displayed in the address bar - the location of the file you're in isn't relevant.

Your view file is at /framework/views/booking/dashboard.php, but the browser just sees the url /framework/booking/dashboard.  That means the browser interprets the location of the resource to be /framework/booking/dashboard/wuxia-blue.css

Personally, I'd recommend just keeping all your css and images outside of the framework in /images and /css.  Otherwise, may have to add some code in your framework to serve up image files, since all the image requests will be running through your framework.php file.

Comment: Sam, thanks. I edited the question slightly. Indeed, I agree structure is silly. I moved the css file in my frustration to try and get it to work. So let me elaborate on what it should be: There is a resources folder on the same level as the 'views' folder. The css files, js files etc... are in there. The framework.php is actually a folder not a file and my url is being served through index.php